# django proxy model's property to a real model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use proxy models to differentiate two user types and add some more attributes through another model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class Patient(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    @property
    def profile(self):
        return self.patientprofile

class PatientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='PatientProfile')
    blood_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    #some attributes here
```

The problem is that I am not sure how should I connect my proxy model's `profile` to a `PatientProfile`. The first thing that comes to mind is to connect them at instance creation time, but it doesn't *feel* right. I think there is a way to link them because the model is a *proxy*. I looked through the documentation, but all I could find is how to use modelManagers...

Comment: Perhaps proxy models are not very suited for this. The simplest solution I think of is to add a field with choices on the `User` model and depending on that accessing the related one to one instances (you can make a property for of that for simplicity).

Comment: I wonder if returning a ```PatientProfile.objects.get(id=self.id)``` in the ```@property``` method would do the trick? Gotta test it tomorrow, but I am hesitating `cause I am not sure if it is a ok to query models inside the model definitions...

Comment: `PatientProfile.objects.get(user_id=self.id)`, although I keep with my point above. A proxy model is not the best way to do this (An extra class which actually has no use here). A field describing the type in the `User` model is what you want along with the One to One relation you already have.

Comment: I have the field to identify different user types as you mentioned. What I want is to add more fields to each of the user types, so I use profiles. The problem was to access these profiles from these users' instances. The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calling does the trick:

```
    @property
    def profile(self):
        return PatientProfile.objects.filter(user_id=self.id)
```